# Does a OneToOne entity need to have a ManyToOne relationship to the parent entity

Tags: jpa

Does a OneToOne entity need to have a ManyToOne relationship to the parent entity or is it not needed?

```
@Entity 
class Foo {

@OneToOne Bar bar;
}

@Entity 
class Bar {

// Do I need to declare a ManyToOne declaration to Foo

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not needed. And it would not be a ManyToOne, it would be a OneToOne...
It would be a ManyToOne if the other side was OneToMany.

Comment: So you are saying Bar doesn't need to have any references back to Foo

Answer (score 0):

No; only if your business need it. You have to reduce navigability between POJOs before creating your JPA mapping. It means if a one-way navigation is enough, don't map a two-way relationship.